# How do I use this substitution for solving this differential equation ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

The equation I have is

$$ t^2(y')+2t(y)-(y^3)=0 $$

I am told that I should use the substitution $ z =2/y^2 .$

How do I get the $z$ equivalents for (I am assuming) $y'$ and $y$ ?
I managed to get the substitution $z' = -1/y^3$ , but have difficulty getting the other 2.

And upon getting the 2 values, am I correct to say I need to sub it in, and put it in the form

$$ z' + p(x)z = q(x) $$

where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are functions

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $z = 2/y^2$, when you take the derivative you should get $z'$ in terms of $y'$ and so forth.  Using the chain rule, $$z' = -\frac{4}{y^3}\cdot y'$$ and since $$y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{z}}$$, you can substitute to get $$t^2(-y^3z'/4) + 2t \sqrt{\frac{2}{z}}- (\sqrt{\frac{2}{z}})^3=0$$ and so
$$t^2(-(\sqrt{\frac{2}{z}})^3z'/4) + 2t \sqrt{\frac{2}{z}}- (\sqrt{\frac{2}{z}})^3=0$$ and dividing out one factor of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{z}}$ should complete the substitution.

Comment: You should not need to introduce square roots, inserting the given DE into the derivative of the substitution should result in only even powers of $y$ that can be directly translated into powers of $z$.

Comment: okay thanks guys! :)

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is of Bernoulli type, the substition $z=y^{-3}$ does not give the right degrees, you need to use $z=y^{-2}$, adding a constant factor to that is more of a convenience than necessary.

---

As a control, you could also just combine the two first terms to get
$$
(t^2y(t))'-y(t)^3=0,
$$
which is a separable equation leading to
$$
\frac{(t^2y)'}{(t^2y)^3}=\frac1{t^6}.
$$

Comment: okay thank you!! :)